# Google Analytics - Does it work for internal applications?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase, google-analytics-sdk, google-analytics-filters, google-analytics-4

We are in the process of integrating Google Analytics for our enterprise applications.
We have few internal applications(can be accessed only within the VPN, not exposed to the outside internet) and few public-facing applications(exposed to the internet).

I had a question: Does google analytics also works for internal applications? can I get the traffic from internal applications?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics sends data to a server outside of your network from the client's browser.

Knowing this, as long as the user's browser has internet access, you will be able to see data in Google Analytics from your internal applications.